# Suspected Error div on web pages of YontooInstallID, Y2PluginIds

Tags: html, web, trojan, intrusion-detection

I have found out that, while `Inspect Element` on chrome or `firebug` on mozilla, i found these strange invisble divs..

how can we remove this.. or is some kind of intrusion...

below is the code

```
<div id="YontooInstallID" style="display: none; ">7811f3e7-3895-42ae-901d-1fd7f3092229</div>
<div id="Y2PluginIds" style="display: none; ">Y2:7811f3e7-3895-42ae-901d-1fd7f3092229</div>
<div id="YontooLocationStore2" style="display: none; ">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask</div>
<div id="dropdowndeals" class="yontoolayerwidget" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; position: fixed; width: 155px; height: 1px; line-height: 0px; z-index: 2147483647; left: 1183px; top: 0px; "><div id="dddContainer" style="position:relative;width:155px; height: 100%">               <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="outline: none; visibility: visible; " data="http://s.nsdsvc.com/App/DddWrapper.swf?c=4" width="100%" height="100%" id="dddContent"><param name="menu" value="false"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="flashvars" value="domain=stackoverflow.com&amp;protocol=http:&amp;clientId=7811f3e7-3895-42ae-901d-1fd7f3092229"></object>            </div></div>

<div id="TopRelatedTopics" class="yontoolayerwidget" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 0px; height: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; "></div>
<div id="TBTMySuperCheap" class="yontoolayerwidget" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; "><div id="swfCom"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unistall this Application from windows control panel.

And Select the second option `Click this option to completely remove yontoo`

[image]